# how to set a Cookie for a HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

*I've read* all related posts I could find but still unable to solve my issue. My application communicates with server using a session cookie, which is stored as an `org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie` object. I use a `HttpClient` for my connections and it works fine.

Authorization:

```
        List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (!cookies.isEmpty()) {
            sessionCookie = cookies.get(0);
            /** multiple cookies usage can be implemented if needed */
        }
```

Each POST to the server:

```
        CookieStore store = client.getCookieStore();
        HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();
        store.addCookie(Tools.getSessionCookie());
        ctx.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, store);
```

I'm kinda new when it comes to cookies but I could notice the `Cookie` object looks (at least in my opinion) a bit similar to a `JSONObject`, having multiple key-values. Now I tried to use the [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) to load many images into a `GridView`. Looking at the `ImageLoader` class I figured out it uses a `HttpUrlConnection`:

```
    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);
    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        //timeouts modified
        conn.setConnectTimeout(GetSettings.getTimeout(context,
                AppConstants.FLAG_CONN_TIMEOUT));
        conn.setReadTimeout(GetSettings.getTimeout(context,
                AppConstants.FLAG_SO_TIMEOUT));
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I was not able to modify it to set the session cookie and of course I'm getting `401 unauthorized` as server response. So basically what I have is an `org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie` object. I've tried `conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", mySessionCookie.getValue());` but it didn't work

**What is the correct way to use the session cookie in my case?**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the `ImageLoader` class the way it now uses a `HttpClient`. However, I'm still looking for a way to set the session cookie using a `HttpUrlConnection` and therefore I'm not marking my own answer as accepted.